# facebook open graph action only shows up in "recent activity", not as individual post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed the open graph object tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) successfully and managed to post an open graph object on my timeline.

However, the post only appeared under the "Recent Activities" box which also includes other activities such as "likes" and "became friends"

How do I actually manage to make the post an individual post in its own feed box (just like if I update my status there will be an individual post only for my status)?  I think it is possible because whenever I comment on pinterest, it manages to show an individual box for my comment action...

thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah! Having just posted a bounty, I'm now pretty sure that the answer is the [Explicit Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/explicit_sharing/) flag...

Comment: actually I kind of figured it out. even with the "explicit sharing" flag you are not guaranteed to have the post show on your timeline. the only 100% success way is to have "user-generated message" in your post, and you have to check that option when you submit your action for approval. now the trick is to attract users to leave a message! :P

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info. It'd be great if you could quickly summarise what you've found out and post it as an answer to your own question -- I'm sure there are other people trying to figure this stuff out, too...

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to fill `Aggregations` on the open graph setting.
[image]

It is so simple to set aggregation on open graph setting.

1. Give the name of aggregation
2. Choose layout
3. Give captions
4. And set other things
5. Save
   Now make some posts and check your timeline :)
   [image]

Comment: I know this answer was posted 2 years ago, but they completely changed the thing now. Any idea where these settings can be found now?

Answer (score 2):

Open Graph activities initially show up only under the Recent Activities section. Once the app has generated considerable traffic, it will start to show up on timelines. The goal for a developer should be to focus on improving the quality of the app, and make it more engaging thereby attracting more users.

Comment: Could you perhaps cite some sources for this? And does this mean that  explicit sharing and/or user-generated messages don't make any difference?

Comment: I can't cite any source with this as I didn't encounter any but my application's activities initially showed up in recent activities then jumped to timeline after I started to have some considerable traffic and huge CTR and conversion rate.

Comment: Well I can attest that explicit sharing AND / OR user generated messages make no difference to getting it out under recent activities and onto the timeline.

Comment: also aggregation or collections as they are now called in open graph made no difference either. Soon I'm going to open this up to our ecommerce site and we'll see if it suddenly starts showing as it did for Deepak.

Comment: This doesn't help when trying to QA/Test

Comment: And especially doesn't help when the review team requires a screenshot of it on your test user timeline and it never actually does show up on the timeline.. Looks like I have to disable message publishing to get approval until enough use of this feature then it'll start showing up on the timeline and then I can enable personalized messages??  Confusing...