# Facebook Open Graph: video not showing up when publishing actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933183/youtube-instead-of-pic-on-facebook-feed-thru-ios-sdk) but now I would like to include youtube video when publishing actions from a webpage instead of posting from a feed dialog on mobile.

My code below is based on the [official facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/). I added the video meta tags based on [another facebook documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/#video). I have authenticated the app and on clicking the Post button received the success alert box. However, when I go to https://www.facebook.com/[MY USERNAME]/activity/[MY ACTION ID], the post shows the title and url and description all right, but I do not see the video thumbnail...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# [MY NAMESPACE]: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/[MY NAMESPACE]#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="[MY APP ID]" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="[MY NAMESPACE]:[MY OBJECT]" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="[MY LINK]" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Object" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/k86xpd26M2g/hqdefault.jpg">
  <meta proprety="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/=yO7B9ERbqdY" />
  <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/yO7B9ERbqdY" />
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis eros metus. Etiam vehicula, eros quis     ultrices pulvinar, sapien orci malesuada sem, malesuada hendrerit lacus massa nec eros. Nullam eget volutpat nunc. Phasellus quis mattis massa. Sed     dolor lacus, rhoncus ut imperdiet ut, euismod eu ipsum." />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function postDialog()
  {
    FB.api(
     '/me/[MY NAMESPACE]:[MY ACTION]',
     'post',
     { dialog: '[MY OBJECT URL]' },
     function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert("Error Type: " + response.error.type + "\n\nMessage: " + response.error.message);
        } else {
          alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
      }
    );
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '[MY APP ID]', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true, // parse XFBML
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
  </script>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Post" onclick="postDialog()" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions:

1) what am I doing wrong? How can I get the video to show in the post?

2) slightly unrelated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945533/facebook-open-graph-action-only-shows-up-in-recent-activity-not-as-individual): my post only shows up in "recent activities" on my profile page and thus does not display the description texts, but I really want the post in my timeline as an individual post. Does this has to do with I haven't submitted this actio for approval yet?

Have been trying to wrestle this the whole afternoon and night... Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `og:url` is pointing to youtube, it should be pointing to the same page the meta tags are on

Comment: thanks. i made a couple of big mistakes with the code previously and just updated the latest code (which is still experiencing the same problem...) Can you take a look again? Thanks